# Access DOM elements of a VAADIN client

Tags: json, dom, automation, vaadin

I pay for a subscription to Company X, I wrote a script to automate my queries to their database. Recently, they updated their site to use VAADIN. That broke my automation method and now I must make hundred of queries a day manually. This has proved problematic as Company X will not support me in automation, though they don't care if I do automate it.

VAADIN obfuscates the DOM elements of the Company X's website and JSON calls.

How do you access DOM elements from a VAADIN style site? The problem I run into is the form fields and buttons do not have targetable / traditional ID's.

Comment: You can use XPath to access the fields.

Comment: Care to elaborate more @murat-k ?

Comment: There is not much to say. With XPath you can navigate to DOM Elements without an ID. [See some examples here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp)

Comment: please provide an example, what makes it impossible now for you to scrape the content.  also add, which tools are used here. with vaadin you will have to make due with positional rules to find your elements. take some hints from selenium examples for vaadin out there.